# Complexity of the inevitability problem over monoids

Tags: fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, regular-language, monoid

I am interested in the complexity of following problem:

> **Inevitability problem in monoids**
>
> Input: two regular languages $K$, $L$ specified by finite monoids $M_K$ and $M_L$ (+ morphisms and accepting sets)
>
> Question: Does $K \subseteq \Sigma^*L\Sigma^*$?

**Question:** What is the complexity of the inevitability problem in monoids? Is it PSpace-complete?

Here is what I know:

- the problem is NL-hard,
- the problem is in PSpace (this follows from the fact that the size of a minimal counter-example to $K \subseteq \Sigma^*L\Sigma^*$ has size at most $|M_K|\cdot2^{|M_L|}$),
- the size of the syntactic monoid for $\Sigma^*L\Sigma^*$ can be exponential in the size of the syntactic monoid for $L$: for instance, take $L = a\Sigma^n a$ for $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$
- the problem $K \subseteq^? L\Sigma^*$ is NL (more generally this holds for languages specified by deterministic automata)
- the problem $K \subseteq^? \Sigma^*L$ is NL (more generally this holds for languages specified by co-deterministic automata)
- the intersection non-emptiness problem for monoids is PSpace-complete by [Fleischer-Kufleitner '18, Theorem 11](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2018/8507/)
- as a consequence of the previous item, $K \subseteq^? \bigcup_i \Sigma^* L_i \Sigma^*$ is PSpace-hard
- the problem would be PSpace-hard if specified by non-deterministic automata, by reduction from the universality problem (reduce $\Sigma^* =^? L$ to $\$\Sigma^*\$ \subseteq^? \Sigma^*\$L\$\Sigma^*$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is PSpace-complete, here is a proof scheme.

We can go back to the proof scheme for PSpace-completeness of regular expression universality, e.g. described in [this answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/40247/parameterized-complexity-of-inclusion-of-regular-languages/40250#40250).

There we can see that the reduction uses a disjunction of expressions $e_0, e_1,e_2,\dots,e_k$, where most expressions $e_i$ are of the form $\Sigma^* f_i \Sigma^*$, where $f_i$ describes a fixed-sized infix, that is a forbidden pattern in a run of the PSpace machine $M$. The exceptions to this are the expressions stating that the prefix does not describe an initial configuration, and about the suffix not describing a final configuration, assume these are $e_0$ and $e_k$.

Let us take $L=f_1+f_2+\dots+f_{k-1}$, and $K$ the language stating that the word starts with an initial configuration and ends with a final one.

We have $K\subseteq \Sigma^*L\Sigma^*$ if and only if the PSpace machine $M$ does not halt. Indeed this inclusion expresses the fact that any word describing a run that starts with an initial configuration and ends with a final one must "cheat" somewhere.

The only thing that remains to be carefully verified is that the monoids of $L$ and $K$ are of polynomial size, but it seems to be the case.

Notice that for some expressions, you can either put them in $L$ or put their complement in $K$, for instance the constraint that in any run you must have exactly one state between any two $\$$. It can either be formulated as a polynomial forbidden pattern everywhere (for $L$), or by a language that you can describe with a small monoid (for $K$).

Bottomline, the intuition is that the main source of nondeterminism that causes the PSpace-hardness of regular expression universality, is the one encoded by expressions of the form $\Sigma^*f\Sigma^*$, i.e. the ability to search for a pattern anywhere in the word.

---

Added from the comments: more precisions on why we can obtain a polynomial-sized monoid for $L$:

The typical job of the syntactic monoid of $L$ will be to recognize a union of languages of the form $p_1\Sigma^*p_2$, where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are small patterns (say of $3$ letters). It is doable with a polynomial size monoid, which just remembers the length of the word and the $3$-letter words on the sides.

You could restrict a lot of the variation in $L$, by choosing for $M$ a universal Turing machine $M_u$ (with polynomial simulation overhead). This way, the number of forbidden local patterns will be a constant, as it will only depend on the transition table of $M_u$, and the only variation in $L$ will be the length $n$ of configurations. The arbitrary PSpace problem will be fully encoded in the initial configuration of the tape, itself encoded in $K$.

Comment: It sounds rather non-obvious to me that the syntactic monoids are of polynomial size. For example, why does the syntactic monoid of $L$ not encode the set of forbidden patterns violated by the current word?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek The typical job of the syntactic monoid of $L$ will be to recognize a union of languages of the form $p_1\Sigma^n p_2$, where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are small patterns (say of 3 letters). It is doable with a polynomial size monoid, which just remembers the length of the word and the 3-letter words on the sides.

Comment: You could even restrict even more the variation in $L$, by choosing for $M$ a universal Turing machine $M_u$ (with polynomial simulation overhead). This way, the number of forbidden local patterns will be a constant, as it will only depend on the transition table of $M_u$, and the only variation in $L$ will be the length $n$ of configurations. The arbitrary PSpace-complete problem will be fully encoded in the initial configuration of the tape, itself encoded in $K$.

Comment: All right, this sounds believable. Could you expand this in the answer itself?

Comment: the comments are added in the answer

Comment: Thanks! Based on your answer, I think you can also show PSpace-hardness by reducing from the PSpace tiling problem (it's exactly the same idea as your reduction). Given a set of tiles, horizontal contraints, vertical constraints, an initial and a final tile, and a width $n$, take $K$ to be the set of sequences of tiles, whose length is a multiple of $n$, whose first tile is the initial one and one last tile is the final one. Take $L$ as the union of languages of the form $st$ [resp. $s\Sigma^{n-1} t$] where $(s,t)$ is a pair of horizontally [resp. vertically] non-compatible tiles.

Comment: @Rémi indeed it's simpler and gets rid of some of the encoding bookkeeping